# How to create a NSImageView with a rounded corner?

Tags: cocoa, nsimageview

Currently now i want to create a round corner NSImageView,i am a newb,how to ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't know if this will work so please try it and we'll cross our fingers.  On the iPhone you can use the `CALayer` of any `UIView` (the `NSView` counterpart in iOS) to get rounded corners.  Based on the reference docs it *appears* that `NSView` supports this but again you'll have to try it.  Please let me know if it works.

```
NSImageView *view = your view;

[view setWantsLayer: YES];  // edit: enable the layer for the view.  Thanks omz

view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
view.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

You can also modify the borderWidth and `borderColor` properties.

Comment: This only works for layer-backed (or layer-hosting) views. You have to call [myView setWantsLayer:YES] first.

Comment: I tried that and it worked nice but when I resize my window the image is redrawn without the cornerRadius, any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: It's important to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`, I didn't think about it and couldn't have found the reason why does this not work. Not everything is just fine :)

Comment: I am sorry, but for for NSImageView, this answer doesn't work at all. I have a normal NSImageView embedded in some other NSView. I set it to "want CALayer" both in .xib and in code (as indicated above). I set it to keep its aspect-ratio, and the pixel leading/traling/top/bottom space relative to superview - the round corners never show. not initially, and not while I resize the window (which resizes the imageView by itself)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used in Swift:

```
imageView.wantsLayer = true
imageView.layer?.borderWidth = 1.0
imageView.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
imageView.layer?.cornerRadius = 25.0
imageView.layer?.masksToBounds = true
```