# Rounded corners for images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icons

I remember seeing the code before which takes a square image (link an iphone icon) and rounds the corners and adds the effects like apple does in iTunes. Basically I get the icon image from iTunes and want to make it look like it does in the store.

Can anyone point me in the direction?

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the `QuartzCore` framework to implement the following:

Your **`iconView`**, *(in this example)* below should be a `UIImageView`:

```
[iconView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[iconView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];

/* setting the border is not necessary, but is an option for you. */
[iconView.layer setBorderWidth:0.0f];
```

Answer (score 1):

to round the corners:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...
int r = 15;
AnyUIViewSubClass.layer.cornerRadius = r;
```

Answer (score 1):

try these links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1850269/215494

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687593/215494

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8334624/215494

that doesn't add the shine/gloss effect, but if your image size is fixed, you could add another `NSImage` of a semi-transparent gloss PNG/JPG on top of it, or you could do it entirely programmatically by drawing intersecting `NSBezierPath`s into `NSImage` and then compositing the result over your rounded-rect image. you could also compose the whole thing into one final `NSImage`.

[Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/) has a very nice article about [creating icons](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/01/advanced-drawing-using-appkit.html) with gloss, shadows, gradients and all.